# Combinations of sets when continually adding new elements

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to figure out the number of sets available at different stages when we continuously add new elements to a baseline set, up to a full set.

For example, if I have a set $X=\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$, and a set $A=\{a,b,c\}$ with $A\subseteq X$, I want to find the sum of set sizes of all sets $A\subseteq B$, $B\subseteq X$.

For this specific example it is easy to do by hand:
At the first stage, we can add any of $d,e,f$ to $A$, so there exist 3 different such sets with size of $|A|+1=4$. At the second stage, we can add two elements, but some of them will be double - in fact there are only 3 different sets fulfilling the conditions for $|A|+2=5$. Finally, naturally, there exists only a single set at $|A|+3=6$, which is $X$ itself.

Therefore, there are  7 sets in total, with the number of sets in the first stage being 3, at the second stage being 3, and at the third stage being 1. I am very much struggling with deriving a general formula for this, in particular at every stage.

Edit: As a comment pointed out, its is actually 8 sets as I should have included A itself as "0th" stage.

Comment: This is just the number of subsets of the difference $X-A$.  In your example, you should have gotten $2^3=8$, not $7$ (unless you meant to exclude $A=B$, though your notation, $A\subseteq B$, clearly allows $A=B$).

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful! However, I am looking in particular for the number of different sets at every stage, i.e. decomposing this

Comment: Ok, and of course it is easy to count the number of subsets of $X-A$ of any desired size.

Comment: Sorry, had a log stuck in my brain. You're right, thank you!

Comment: No worries.  $\quad$.